# SlowCheetah not working on c# console application

Tags: c#, slowcheetah

I'm trying to use Slow Cheetah XML Transforms with console application using c#
When I right click on the app.config file there is no "Add Transform" item in the menu.

and the "SlowCheetah" is installed with the application and can be found in the packages.config file

```
<packages>
<package id="SlowCheetah" version="2.5.10.6"/>
</packages>
```

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You need to install the [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) (different from a NuGet package) in order to see context menu options.

Comment: hi @Asad its already installed! and i cannot find the option in the menu

Comment: it has been solved, the solution is : Uninstall SlowCheeta, re-install it, restart visual studio. Thanks

Comment: If you have found the solution, please post it as an answer yourself and mark it as accepted, so that it's clearly shown that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:

1- Uninstall SlowCheetah. 
2- Install it again using [This Link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)! 
3- Referesh Visual Studio